# Doctrine equivalent of in() expression with dates

Tags: php, doctrine, query-builder

Using Doctrine's `QueryBuilder`, I attempted to use the [`in()`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.7/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.html#method_in) method on an array of dates but I found out it only allows string values.

```php
/** @param DateTime[] $dates */
public function findByDate(array $dates): array {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('Event');
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('Event.date', ':dates'));
    $qb->setParameter('dates', $dates);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT [...]' with params [{"date":"2020-01-31 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe/Berlin"}]: 
>   Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTimeImmutable could not be converted to string

Is there any easy equivalent of `in()` function working with dates ? (preferably not using DQL)

Comment: [Related.](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/6934) I would suggest the `array_map` approach that is suggested by kejwmen there. Simple enough.

Comment: @Jeto Sure... But can we be certain the `Y-m-d H:i:s` format is working on any db implementation/distro/setup (is it kinda SQL standard?), or may it vary depending on the db server?

Comment: Sure, this might be less portable this way. I don't know enough about Doctrine, but there may be a way to force a date format of a column, and then possibly retrieve that when doing the above. In any case, your solution looks fine to me (you might want to try and make it more generic and post it on that github issue).

Comment: Good idea :) Added a comment on that issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with, looping over the PHP array, building another array of `eq()` expressions, and then `or`ing everything.
It does its job but needs to declare one parameter per date in the array instead of one single array parameter.

Let me know if you find some better way...

```php
/** @param DateTime[] $dates */
public function findByDate(array $dates): array {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('Event');
    $criteria = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {
        $criteria[] = $qb->expr()->eq('Event.date', ":date_$i");
        $qb->setParameter("date_$i", $dates[$i]);
    }
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX()->addMultiple($criteria));
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```